# Spring Boot Properties - Why am I getting the error EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression 'hash(#)'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, spring-el

I have added a properties file in my Spring boot application which I am using to initialize some values for my program. This is working for simple values, and some slightly more complicated ones, like the examples I have created for value.a and value.b shown below.

```
my.value.a=a
my.value.b=b

value.a = #{ systemEnvironment['MY_VALUE_A'] != null ? systemEnvironment['MY_VALUE_A'] : '${my.value.a}' }
value.b = #{ systemEnvironment['MY_VALUE_B'] != null ? systemEnvironment['MY_VALUE_B'] : '${my.value.b}' }
```

I'd like to do something fancy to combine these, like in value.c below, however, this is giving me an error. Is this me trying to do something to complex for a properties file? Or is there an error I have made here somewhere?

```
value.c = #{ systemEnvironment['MY_VALUE_C'] != null ? systemEnvironment['MY_VALUE_C'] : '#{ ${value.a}:${value.b} }' }
```

It doesn't compile with value.c like this, but gives a stack trace with the error:

> InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'MyProperties': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setValueC' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'hash(#)' -> [Help 1]

To set the values in Java, I have a properties file and the method where the values are set looks like this:

```
@Value("${value.a}")
public void setValueA(String value) {
    this.a = value;
}

@Value("${value.b}")
public void setValueB(String value) {
    this.b = value;
}

@Value("${value.c}")
public void setValueC(String value) {
    this.c = value;
}
```

The output I am trying to achieve is for value.c to come in as a:b - or whatever environment variables a and b are substituted for, separated by a colon.

I'm not that familiar with this, so I may be going about this completely wrong. Is it possible to achieve what I want in this manner? What have I done wrong if it is?

Comment: You cannot have nested SPEL. It it not supported as far as i know

Comment: I have nested placeholders in value.a and value.b nested inside an expression, but value.c has an expression nested in an expression, which from a quick Google might not be supported now you mention it. Thank you, for your comment, you have saved me some headache.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Please try this:

```
value.c = #{ systemEnvironment['MY_VALUE_C'] != null ? systemEnvironment['MY_VALUE_C'] : ${value.a} + ':' + ${value.b} }
```

---

**Option 2**

If that does not work, another option would be to move the logic to the `@Value` annotation in Java code. For example, `value.c` could be left having a possible `null` value:

```
value.c = #{ systemEnvironment['MY_VALUE_C'] }
```

And then in Java code:

```
@Value("#{ ${value.c} != null ? ${value.c} : ${value.a} + ':' + ${value.b} }")
public void setValueC(String value) {
    this.c = value;
}
```

See [SpEL documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions) for more information on available operators and syntax.